# Select rows from with same values in one column but different value in the other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have some duplicates in my data that I need to correct.

This is a sample of a dataframe:

```
    test = pd.DataFrame({'event_id':['1','1','2','3','5','6','9','3','9','10'],
                 'user_id':[0,0,0,1,1,3,3,4,4,4],
                 'index':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]})
```

I need to select all the rows that have equal values in `event_id` but differing values in `user_id`. I tried this (based on a similar question but with no accepted answer):

```
test.groupby('event_id').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['event_id', 'user_id'], keep="first")

out:

    event_id    user_id index
0   1           0       10
3   3           1       40
6   9           3       70
7   3           4       80
8   9           4       90
```

But I do not need the first row where user_id is the same - `0`.

The second part of the question is - what is the best way to correct the duplicate record? How could I add a suffix to `event_id` (`_new`) but only in this row:

```
    event_id    user_id index
3   3_new       1       40
6   9_new       3       70
7   3           4       80
8   9           4       90
```

Answer (score 2):

Ummm, I try to fix your code

```
test.groupby('event_id').
      filter(lambda x : (len(x['event_id'])==x['user_id'].nunique())&(len(x['event_id'])>1))
Out[85]: 
  event_id  user_id  index
3        3        1     40
6        9        3     70
7        3        4     80
8        9        4     90
```

For Correct the duplicate row, you can do with create a new sub key , personally not recommended modify your original columns .

```
df['subkey']=df.groupby('event_id').cumcount()
```

Comment: No, subkey is not what I need.

Comment: @aviss this is  more data safety

Comment: What I meant is that subkey doesn't generate '1's for rows in question...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
test[test.duplicated(['event_id'], keep=False) & 
     ~test.duplicated(['event_id','user_id'], keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
  event_id  user_id  index
3        3        1     40
6        9        3     70
7        3        4     80
8        9        4     90
```